# What data structure fits this description?

Tags: data-structures

I need a data structure that holds unique values (like a set), but also sorts them (like a priority queue) and allows random access for binary searching (like an array). Which type of data structure would fit these needs? I could live without the sorting (I can always sort it myself at the end)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds like a balanced binary tree, with a restriction of uniqueness in its insert operation, and implementing the `OS-SELECT` operation (see: [Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844), chapter 14 in the 3rd edition) for retrieving an element given its rank ("index") in O(lg n).

The proposed data structure and augmented operations will allow you to:

- Hold unique values, performing the insertion operation in O(lg n)
- Keep the elements sorted, with a O(lg n) search operation
- Access an element given its rank in O(lg n)

Comment: @KingsIndian: The OP hasn't specified a desired time complexity for random access...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Since OP mentioned "like-an-array", I thought OP expects constant-time access.

Comment: @KingsIndian certainly, it's possible to retrieve an element given its rank in O(lg n) in a binary search tree (see: procedure OS-SELECT in [CLRS](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Thomas-H-Cormen/dp/0262033844))

Comment: @KingsIndian My requirement for random access was for efficient searching. If a binary tree gives me efficient searching, I don't need random access.

Comment: @baruch I updated my answer with the time complexity for the required operations, I hope it's enough for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

how about a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) or a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)?

- unique values - both store unique values only
- sorting - both sort entries either using natural order of elements or by the custom Comparator provided to them
- random access - both provide random (O(1)) access.

Comment: The question doesn't specify that the data structure has to be implemented in Java. Besides, both `TreeSet` and `TreeMap` _are_ balanced binary trees, implemented as Red-Black trees. And your last point is incorrect, they _do not_ offer O(1) random access. For the `TreeMap` the documentation specifies O(lg n) time cost for the `containsKey`, `get`, `put` and `remove` operations and O(lg n) for add, `remove` and `contains` operations of the `TreeSet`